# Display multiple rows when more than one similar email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have the following DE called Metering_ElecDE_email

[image]

Where there is a match with **Email** (in this case 1)i want the Email to display as per below.

Supply address: Hamilton (next line)
ICP: ert (next line)
Customer number: 321 (next line)

Supply address: Auckland (next line)
ICP: ert (next line)
Customer number: 432

I have the below which (i know) is wrong. Any help here is appreciated.

```
%%[ var @rows, @row, @rowcount, @i, @ICP, @supply_address, @customer_number, @Emailaddress,
set @rows = lookupRows ("Metering_ElecDE_email", "subscriber_key",_subscriberkey” )

set @rowcount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowcount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowcount do

set @row = row(@rows, @i) /*get row based on loop counter */

set @ICP = field(@row,"ICP")
set @site_address = field(@row,"supply_address")
set @party_code = field(@row,"customer_number")
]%% 


ICP: %%=v(@icp)=%%
Supply address: %%=v(@supply_address)=%%
Customer number: %%=v(@customer_number)=%%

%%[next @i]%%

%%[endif]%%
```

I am not getting the desired output. Sorry am not a coder.

Comment: what is wrong? I don't see an endif and your lookup rows should be on email instead of emailaddress and what does @email set to?

Comment: i have edited the script.

Comment: what does the current output look like? Your lookuprows still looks incorrect I believe you should have something like lookupRows("Metering_ElecDE_email", "email",_subscriberkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you simply have a bunch of typos in your code if your DE image is accurate, I believe this may fix your issue:

```
%%[ var @rows, @row, @rowcount, @i, @ICP, @supply_address, @customer_number, @Emailaddress,
set @rows = lookupRows("Metering_ElecDE_email", "email",emailaddr )

set @rowcount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowcount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowcount do

set @row = row(@rows, @i) /*get row based on loop counter */

set @ICP = field(@row,"ICP")
set @site_address = field(@row,"supply address")
set @party_code = field(@row,"customer number")
]%% 


ICP: %%=v(@icp)=%%
Supply address: %%=v(@site_address)=%%
Customer number: %%=v(@party_code)=%%

%%[next @i]%%

%%[endif]%%
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RahulG please mark the answer accepted if it was helpful